# Implment iOS system opening app zoom in/out animation effect

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

If user turn on the iOS 7 or above dynamic effect, when user taps an app icon, the system will have a zoom out/in effect for the app icon and its view, then go to start the app. I want to achieve similar zoom out/in animation. Any good implementations?

I got most code ready, like below, but not the exact animation I want:

```
@implementation PushAnimator

    - (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
        return 0.5;
    }

    - (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
        UIViewController* toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
        UIViewController* fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
        [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:toViewController.view];
        toViewController.view.alpha = 0;
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        MCAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MCAppDelegate *)app.delegate;
    //    CGRect fromFrame = appDelegate.UserTouchView.frame;
    //    CGRect toFrame = toViewController.view.frame;
    //    
        CGFloat xFactor = fromViewController.view.frame.size.width / appDelegate.UserTouchView.frame.size.width;
        CGFloat yFactor = fromViewController.view.frame.size.height / appDelegate.UserTouchView.frame.size.height;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
            appDelegate.UserTouchView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(xFactor,yFactor);
            toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
            toViewController.view.alpha = 1;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
        }];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Depends on what entity you want to implement the animation.

Comment: Say I got a UICollectionCell, and when user click the cell, the cell will have the same zoom effect, and do a pushViewController. I got most code ready, but the animation effect is not perfect. I just need the animation code.

Comment: If it really is a UICollectionCell then you got to make a Custom Segue class with its own Animation,
Try this link if you are coding in swift.
http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/

Comment: You can also check this link:  http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2013/01/15/custom-view-controller-transitions-using-uistoryboardsegues/

Comment: I have updated my question, I got the animator ready, but the effect is not like the exact system one, mine is flaw.

Comment: @GauravSingh  I am not looking for segues... I am looking for the animation portion code. See my question, I have a rough animation ready, but not perfect, need enhancements, but I am not sure how to animte like the system one

Comment: @Wingzero have you executed that project code about what it does?

Comment: yes, I have running it, it will has a zoom in/out effect, but not perfect.